# Swift: Loading Codable Class into CoreData from JSON is generating Objects with all properties to nil

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data, codable

**Background:** 
I am creating a game with the option to buy/use power-ups. I want to pre-load these power-up objects into my CoreData database with a quantity of 0. The idea being that the user will buy power-ups and then the context of how many they own is saved in the database.

**Problem:**
My Codable objects are being generated with the properties all being nil or 0, i.e. not taking on the information provided by the JSON. Please can you help me see where I am going wrong.

My Codable conforming Class:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class PowerUp: NSManagedObject, Codable {

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case desc
        case image
        case quantity
    }

    var name: String?
    var desc: String?
    var image: String?
    var quantity: Double?

    required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        guard let codingUserInfoKeyManagedObjectContext = CodingUserInfoKey.context,
            let context = decoder.userInfo[codingUserInfoKeyManagedObjectContext] as? NSManagedObjectContext,
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "PowerUp", in: context) else {
            fatalError("Failed to decode PowerUp")
        }

        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.desc = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .desc)
        self.image = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .image)
        self.quantity = try container.decodeIfPresent(Double.self, forKey: .quantity)
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(self.name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(self.desc, forKey: .desc)
        try container.encode(self.image, forKey: .image)
        try container.encode(self.quantity, forKey: .quantity)
    }
}

public extension CodingUserInfoKey {
    // Helper property to retrieve the context
    static let context = CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "context")
}
```

My JSON (powerUpData.json):

```
[
    {
        "name": "Extra Time",
        "desc": "Wind back the clock with an extra 30 seconds.",
        "image": "sand-clock",
        "quantity": 0.0
    },
    {
        "name": "Voice Trade",
        "desc": "Offload an asset to a friend for 10% more than originally paid.",
        "image": "microphone",
        "quantity": 0.0
    }
]
```

My AppDelegate (where the decoding and pre-loading is done):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        preloadPowerUps()
        return true
    }

// Skipped out non-edited, irrelevant AppDelegate functions for clarity...

func preloadPowerUps() {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "powerUpData", withExtension: "json") else { fatalError("no file") }
        do {
            let json = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            print(json)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.userInfo[CodingUserInfoKey.context!] = persistentContainer.viewContext
            do {
                let subjects = try decoder.decode([PowerUp].self, from: json)
                print(subjects)
                do {
                    try persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
                } catch {
                    print("error")
                }
            } catch {
                print("error")
            }
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }
```

What's more is that when debugging, my PowerUp objects do seem to be taking on the values of my json but also kind of not...
[image: AppDelegate debugging]

Comment: So `print(subjects)` gives the correct results? Where do you print the incorrect results?

Comment: In the console print(subjects) actually prints out the objects with nil properties like you see in the box on the right hand side. But the debugger seems to be telling me that the object of subjects is actually holding the right data.

Comment: Yes, you save to CoreData *after* your print(), so that is expected.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, why would you expect ```print(subjects)``` to print nil even though saving to CoreData is done afterwards? Any idea why its not saving correctly?

Comment: The left pane shows the subjects, the right pane shows what is in your CoreData database. But you save your CoreData context a few lines later (`try persistentContainer.viewContext.save()`). So at the `print(subjects)` line, your database is still empty, which is what you see in the right pane.

Comment: Just tried swapping the order round so ```print(subjects)``` is done after but the console is still printing the nil objects. Also I have checked the actual database and all I see saved are the null entries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210693/discussion-between-koen-and-rc1ironman).

Comment: You may need to attribute your properties with `@NSManaged`, i.e. **@NSManaged var name: String?**. CoreData may not be receiving the values as they are decoded. That would explain why they are present in the print output but not in the entity after the save.

Comment: Wow @richardpiazza that works! I can get around the problem of NSNumber not conforming to Codable by typecasting the encoding and decodings too. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize from the questions comments:

It's important to remember that CoreData still relies heavily on Objective-C. In your example code, the properties on your class, although expressible as CoreData attributes, the implementation is not being handled by CoreData.

You'll need to add the `@NSManaged` attribute to your properties like this:

```swift
@NSManaged var name: String?
@NSManaged var desc: String?
@NSManaged var image: String?
@NSManaged var quantity: Double?
```

This will expose them to Obj-C as dynamic and allow CoreData to handle the implementation. This would also help to explain your debugging, in that at runtime the print statement would show values, but the saved managed object had nil values.